# Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 - stuck on login screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, login-screen, amd-graphics

I just installed ubuntu 16.04, which I'm dual-booting with windows 10 on a separate drive. When I boot, I'm greeted with this screen and nothing else:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbuVb.jpg

I can open a terminal (tty) and log in, but then I have no idea what to do. All I can see on google is that people have tried to reinstall their proprietary graphics drivers, but mine aren't proprietary (just the open source Radeon driver - I'm using a Radeon R9 390) and reinstalling them did nothing. Do you have any ideas?

EDIT: I was rebooting as I was making this post, and on this attempt it was, at first, still stuck, but after logging in through tty and closing it (Ctrl-Alt-F7), it showed me a field for my password, and now everything seems to work as normal.

EDIT2: Rebooted again, same problem.

Final edit: It.. err... turns out I had to move my pointer to show the login prompt. Still weird that I can't get it to show with keyboard input alone. Problem solved though.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like the problem is solved because the login prompt should appear automatically.